# Laravel one-to-many relationship - a reference to a non-existent field

Tags: php, laravel, one-to-many, relation

What do I forget about doing migrations in Lavarel that once relations act to me like this and once so? Presenting what I want to get is I want to assign the user his order and order the products he ordered. So I have a User table, the Order table, and the OrderProduct table. Usera table with one-to-many relation with the Order table, Order table with one-to-many relation with the OrderProduct table. Starting from the relation Order and OrderProduct, I get an error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'order_products_tables.order_table_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `order_products_tables` where `order_products_tables`.`order_table_id` = 1 and `order_products_tables`.`order_table_id` is not null)
```

And this error says clearly and clearly that he can not find the order_table_id column in the order_products_tables table and I am not surprised what it may sound silly because there is no such field but there is an order_id field and in migrations is described with which field is the relationship and I can not understand why Laravel tries refer to order_products_tables.

Migrations Order:

```
Schema::create('order_tables', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');

    $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->nullable();

    $table->foreign('user_id')
        ->references('id')
        ->on('users');

    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Migrations OrderProduct:

```
Schema::create('order_products_tables', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');

    $table->integer('order_id')->unsigned();

    $table->integer('count')->unsigned();
    $table->integer('price')->unsigned();

    $table->foreign('order_id')
        ->references('id')
        ->on('order_tables');

    $table->timestamps();
});
```

As it results from the migration, the order_products_tables table stores the record ID from the order_tables table and the relationship is based on that ID.

Model Order table:

```
class OrderTable extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'order_tables';

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'id');
    }

    public function products()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\OrderProductTable');
    }
}
```

Model OrderProduct table:

```
class OrderProductTable extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'order_products_tables';

    public function order()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(OrderTable::class, 'id');
    }
}
```

I do not understand why the reference to order_table_id is going. I have done other relations, eg User and Order on the same principle, and it works without a problem, suddenly here I have such a case. Where should I look for a solution and why does it wo

Comment: Try adding the column into the relationship. It will automatically look for `{related_table_name}_id` in the table. If the column name is different, you can specify it in the relationship. The order is usually `Related class, foreign key, local key`

Comment: When I add return $this->belongsTo(OrderTable::class, 'id', 'order_id'); to OrderProductTable I have the same error. But when I change field name from order_id to order_table_id it's working. Thank you! But is it possible that all other relationships I have in this way and work only now I jumped out something like that? Should I change the rest?

Comment: It's possible the other relationships are fine. It's only when the column name schema doesn't match what Eloquent is looking for that you may have issues.

Answer (score 1):

This error comes from using *wrong* table names or, to be more correct, not defining the relationship correctly. The following relationship definitions will fix your issue:

```
class OrderTable extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'order_tables';

    public function products()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\OrderProductTable', 'order_id', 'id');
    }
}

class OrderProductTable extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'order_products_tables';

    public function order()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(OrderTable::class, 'order_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

The reason your previous code did not work is that Laravel uses default values which are basically assumptions and require your database to follow certain naming conventions. Here is a list of conventions you should follow*:

- Tables should be named after the model name in plural form and snake_case:

  - Model `User` is supposed to have a table named `users`.
  - Model `Category` is supposed to have a table named `categories` (see the english plural).
  - Model `AccountManager` is supposed to have a table named `account_managers`.
- If there is no model for a table, i.e. a many-to-many relationship table, the table name is expected to be in singular form and snake_case, where the model names that hold the relation are ordered alphabetically:

  - If there are models `Category` and `Product` (with tables `categories` and `products`) and there is a many-to-many relationship (`belongsToMany()`) between them, the table for the pivot table is expected to be called `order_product` (and not `product_order` because `o` comes before `p` in the alphabet).
- Foreign key columns are expected to be called after the model they represent with `_id` as postfix:

  - When referencing the `User` model on a `BlogPost` model for example, Laravel expects a `user_id` column as foreign key on the `BlogPost` model. The referenced primary key on the `User` model is taken from the `$primaryKey` property, which is `'id'` by default.

For your particular scenario, this means we would expect the following models, tables and columns:

- Model `User` with table `users` and columns like in the default migration of Laravel.
- Model `Order` with table `orders` and columns like `id`, `user_id`, `created_at`, ...
- Model `Product` with table `products` and columns like `id`, `name`, `price`, ...
- Model `OrderProduct` with table `order_products` and columns like `id`, `order_id`, `product_id`, `quantity`, ...

In theory, the model `OrderProduct` is not necessary. You should also be able to build the same system without it by defining `$this->belongsToMany(Product::class)->withPivot('quantity')` on the `Order` model and `$this->belongsToMany(Order::class)->withPivot('quantity')` on the `Product` model (note the pivot fields). Personally, I prefer extra models for many-to-many relations though.

For reference to Eloquent relationships, have a look [at the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships). There are examples for all relationship types and additional information for the additional parameters when you need to override the default table or column names for your relations.

** This list may lack important information. It was created as best effort.*