# SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, many-to-many

I would like to get many "badges" to one "company"
I have 3 tables companies, badgy, badgy_company as pivot table.
What should I try/do? Can someone give me a hint or something?

#### company.blade.php

```
@foreach($listings->badgy as $type)
    <span class="label label-default">{!! $type->title !!}</span>
@endforeach
```

#### Badgy.php

```
class Badgy extends Model{

protected $table = 'badgy';

public function badgy()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Company::class);        
}
```

If I remove `protected $table = 'badgy';` I get error:

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'MYDATABASE.badgies' doesn't exist

#### Company.php

```
public function badgy()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Badgy::class);        
}
```

In page controllers I try:

```
$listings = Company::find($id);
$listings = Company::query()->get();
```

If I need to provide any more info, please, just ask.

Comment: `php artisan migrate`, your table badgies not exist

Comment: Is your table badges or badgy?

Comment: My table in phpmyadmin is badgy.

Comment: Edited.    I have tables; companies, badgy, badgy_company as pivot table.

Comment: OK.  Your error also doesn't match.  What is the full error from the title?

Comment: have you created your pivot table?

Comment: Yes, pivot table is badgy_companies. Schema::table('badgy_company', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('badgy')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('company_id')->references('id')->on('companies')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }

Comment: Full error title: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'p2pbasedata.badgies' doesn't exist (SQL: select `badgies`.*, `badgy_company`.`company_id` as `pivot_company_id`, `badgy_company`.`badgy_id` as `pivot_badgy_id` from `badgies` inner join `badgy_company` on `badgies`.`id` = `badgy_company`.`badgy_id` where `badgy_company`.`company_id` = 1) (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\xyxy\resources\views\pages\xxxx.blade.php)

Comment: If your variable `$listings` is meant to contain your companies, and you want for each companies to display its "badgy", so you miss the definition of the `Company` class in your post. Please provide it and we can help you more.

Comment: Please edit your original question to incorporate the additional information you provided in comments, and format it so others won't have to read all the comments to understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: Company class have: /**
     * A company is belongs to many categories
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
     */
    public function badgy()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Badgy::class);
        
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not following the Laravel naming conventions. As a result, the default values used for relations by the framework don't work. You will have to set them manually as follows:

```
class Badgy
{
    protected $table = 'badgy'; // Laravel default would be 'badgies'

    public function companies()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Company::class, 'badgy_company', 'category_id', 'company_id');
    }
}

class Company
{
    protected $table = 'companies'; // optional as the default is the same

    public function badgies()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Badgy::class, 'badgy_company', 'company_id', 'category_id');
    }
}
```

Please also have a look at [another answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51504607/laravel-one-to-many-relationship-a-reference-to-a-non-existent-field/51506146#51506146) where I explain some important pieces regarding relationships and naming conventions. Because in a perfect scenario you would have the following tables and columns:

```
companies:
  - id
  - name

badgies:
  - id
  - title

badgy_company:
  - id
  - badgy_id
  - company_id
```

Which would allow your models to look like this:

```
class Badgy
{
    public function companies()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Company::class);
    }
}

class Company
{
    public function badgies()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Badgy::class);
    }
}
```